# Does making changes in files in node_modules restart nodemon?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemon

[image]

```
 {
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node bin/server.js",
        "dev":"nodemon bin/server.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.15",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dates": "^12.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "webpack": "^4.43.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
      }
    }
```

The `nodemon` restarts my server when I make changes in the `src` folder. But, when I make changes in the files present in `core-npm` which is in `node_modules`, `nodemon` does not restart.

Can it be done with `nodemon` or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: node_modules is ignored by default. You can override this in your nodemon configuration https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#overriding-the-underlying-default-ignore-rules

Comment: Where should the nodemon.json be saved? Can I ignore all the node_modules except core-npm?

Answer (score 0):

```
nodemon bin/server.js --watch . --watch folderLocation/core-npm
```

The above line will alos watch for changes in the specified location. For me, its `core-npm` in `node_modules`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.